# How to use an instance of a class as a key of a Record<k,v>

Tags: typescript

I want to use a instance of a class as a `key` of a `Record<key,value>` but since only  `'string | number | symbol` are allowed types for the key I was wondering if there a good ways to achieve this. I was trying to utilize the `Symbol.toPrimitive` function but TS won't let me.

Example:

```
class myTestClass{
  constructor(val: string) {
    this.value = val;
  }
  value:string;
  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint: "number" | "string" | "default"): number | string {
    if (hint === "number") {
      return parseInt(this.value);
    }
    return this.value;
  }
}
export const MYRECORD: Record<myTestClass, someOther> = {};
```

The error I get:

```
Type 'myTestClass' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'.   Type 'myTestClass' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.
```

What is the best way to archive such behaviour?

Comment: This issue is being tracked in https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4538

Comment: Is there a workaround of such sorts?

Comment: A workaround might be to stringify

Comment: Since your `[Symbol.toPrimitive]` just returns the value of the parameter passed to the constructor, two difference instances with the same value, when used to index an object, would just refer to the same property value on the object. In that case, you could just use that value as the object key and achieve the same results. Alternatively, JavaScript's `Map` seem like a better fit for using non-primitives/objects as keys.

Comment: you are right Map is a better choice